# How do you check the state of a POCO that is attached to the EF Context?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What is the way to check the State of an entity which is a POCO (not derived from EntityObject) and that is attached to the EF context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the DbContext and c is your entity reference

```
            var state = Context.Entry(c).State;
```

if you are using ObjectContext.

```
//if x is your entity reference
var state = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(x);
```

Comment: I suspect the first example will make a db call if the entity is not found in the DBContext.

Answer (score 1):

if you are employing an identifier field and using `DBContext`, you may check using the following, assuming that the `Id` of entity is entityId;

```
if(Context.Entities.Local.Any(q => q.Id == entityId))
{
    // already attached to the context
}
```

refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592872):

> The Local property of DbSet provides simple access to the entities of
>   the set that are currently being tracked by the context and have not
>   been marked as Deleted. Accessing the Local property never causes a
>   query to be sent to the database.